# p:commandButton update action won't clear input fields after submission

Tags: ajax, primefaces

```
<h:form id="registrationForm">
            UserName:
            <p:inputText id="usernameInput" value="#{userUI.thisUsername}" />
    <br />
            Password:
            <p:inputText id="passwordInput" value="#{userUI.thisPassword}" />
    <br />
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{userUI.createUser}" 
            update="registrationForm" value="Create" />
</h:form>
```

I want this form to reset its values after submission.
I enter the username and password, hit submit, it resets the values and persists empty values, not the ones i entered. Tried moving the commandButton out of h:form but it didn't change a thing. Also tried adding
`<p:ajax update="registrationForm" resetValues="true" />`
It still persisted empty values.
How do i do it right?

Comment: Is your bean called UserUI? And did you have a setter and a getter called `setThisUsername(String thisUsername)` and `getThisUsername()`? In addition, when you write `actionListener="#{userUI.createUser}` the correspponding signature is `public void actionListener(ActionEvent event)` so you might write `actionListener="#{userUI.createUser()}"` or `action="#{userUI.createUser}"` if your method signature is `public void createUser()`

Comment: does the application hit field setters or action listener method on debug?

Comment: make sure you have getter setter on fields, and what is your backing bean scope? also try changing your actionListener to action

Comment: Yes, my bean is called UserUI and the class has getters/setters for thisUsername and ThisPassword.
I have tried variations of what Mathieu sougested, but it still persists empty values.
I have provided no scope annotation for my bean class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:
Bean is of scoped Request.
 To reset values reinitialize fields in post constructor, or call it manually in your createUser method.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UserUI implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String thisUsername;
    private String thisPassword;

    public UserUI(){
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
       thisUsername="";
       thisPassword="";
    }

    public void createUser(){
        System.out.println("ThisUserName :"+thisUsername);
        System.out.println("thisPassword :"+thisPassword);
        init();
    }


    /////////GETTER SETTER
    //thisUsername
    //thisPassword
}
```

Your webPage.xhtml will be look like:

```
<h:form id="registrationForm">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">

            <h:outputLabel value="UserName:" for="usernameInput" />
            <p:inputText id="usernameInput" value="#{userUI.thisUsername}" />

            <h:outputLabel value="Password:" for="passwordInput" />
            <p:inputText id="passwordInput" value="#{userUI.thisPassword}" />

            <p/>
            <p:commandButton action="#{userUI.createUser}" update="@form" value="Create" />
            </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: This works as intended (persists values that are put in the fields), but the values do not get reset to empty after submission.

Comment: The values are still there after hitting create.

Comment: I have added a call to `userUI()` (the one setting the values to empty) to the `createUser()` method and it worked. I will accept your answer if you edit it accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I have added PostContruct you can also check this method.